# Create video from images sorted in numerical order using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, png

I have a bunch of images named `pic1.png`, `pic2,png`, `pic24.png` ,... etc. How can I use ffmpeg to create a video from them? I have tried

```
    ffmpeg -f image2 -r $FRAMERATE -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" output.mp4
```

but it does not sort the images in the right order. Is it because of the naming convention I used? (`pic2.png` instead of `pic002.png`)

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
ffmpeg -framerate $FRAMERATE -i "pic%d.png" output.mp4
```

for the filename pattern you described.

If the names were like `pic002.png`, you would use `"pic%03d.png"` instead.